# combine same data from two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Due to some changes in business logic I had to change the way I was storing phone numbers into a new table. New user phone numbers are no longer being stored in the `Old Table` but to a `New Table`.

I am required to generate a report which would include the basic user details and phone numbers of each user either from the `Old Table` or from the `New Table` where ever it may be found.

For example in the tables below `User` : `Chadwick` while `User` : `Mary` has her data in both the tables.

How could I combine the phone numbers into a single columns by filling the missing data from the 'New Table`.

Old User Table

```
id      username        phone_number
1       sam             1122331100
2       CHADWICK        
3       harry           6633998800
4       clark           1133446600
5       MARY            1155448800
```

New User Table

```
id      username        phone_no
500     CHADWICK        6655441100
501     omar            9955110000
502     tchala          4422553300
503     gary            7755886600
504     sasha           3366998800
505     MARY            1155448800
```

Comment: Is username unique in both?

Comment: yes username is unique

Answer (score 2):

Since users are not always found in both tables, then a simple coalesce won't necessarily work here. You could probably still figure out a coalesce query, but here's an alternative solution, where you union two queries together, then select from it where the phone number is not null.

```
    select *
    from (
        select username, phone_number as phone_number
        from old_table
        union
        select username, phone_no as phone_number
        from new_table
        )z
    -- where phone_number is not null -- if integer
       where phone_number <> '' -- if string
```

**EDIT:** Per comments below, you mentioned that phone number is string. So change that last row per the comment I put into the code above.

DB-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rqULCvDKW4n2M2CiCgZzFR/0):

Comment: i deleted a some `users` with phone numbers from one of the tables and tried your query both ways by switching which select statement in the sub query comes before and after the `UNION` the query is still selecting a lot of `Null` values

Comment: What is the column format of phone_number in both tables?

Comment: could you explain what you mean by column format ?

Comment: Is the phone number integer or string? Also, if it's blank are you sure it's blank or rather filled with some spaces?

Comment: the `phone_number` is string i am checking if the data includes just spaces

Comment: there are either `Null`s or 10 digit phone_numbers and no rows with spaces or blanks

Comment: i am okay with a solution that will select the `phone_numbers` from the `New Table` into another column and not necessarily the same column

Comment: if you change the last row to: where phone_number <> '' then does it work

Comment: yes looks like it is working now. i will investigate furthur. Phone numbers of the `users` that i had deleted are no longer showing as Null but has the correct phone number in the result